# Is there a Perl equivalent to Python's `if __name__ == '__main__'`?

Tags: python, perl, executable

Is there a way to determine if the current file is the one being executed in Perl source? In Python we do this with the following construct:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    # This file is being executed.
    raise NotImplementedError
```

I can hack something together using `FindBin` and `__FILE__`, but I'm hoping there's a canonical way of doing this. Thanks!

Answer (score 49, accepted):

```
unless (caller) {
  print "This is the script being executed\n";
}
```

See [caller](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/caller.html).  It returns `undef` in the main script.  Note that that doesn't work inside a subroutine, only in top-level code.

Answer (score 10):

See the "Subclasses for Applications (Chapter 18)" portion of [brian d foy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8817/brian-d-foy)'s article [Five Ways to Improve Your Perl Programming](http://www.onlamp.com/pub/a/onlamp/2007/04/12/five-ways-to-improve-your-perl-programming.html).

Answer (score 4):

`unless caller` is good, but a more direct parallel, as well as a more *explicit check*, is:

```
use English qw<$PROGRAM_NAME>;

if ( $PROGRAM_NAME eq __FILE__ ) { 
    ...
}
```

Just thought I'd put that out there.

**EDIT**

Keep in mind that `$PROGRAM_NAME` (or '`$0`') is writable, so this is not absolute. But, in most practice--except on accident, or rampaging modules--this likely won't be changed, or changed at most [locally](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?perlfunc#local) within another scope.

Comment: That's not guaranteed to work.  For one thing, $0 (the real name of $PROGRAM_NAME) is actually a writable variable in Perl.  But __FILE__ isn't affected by changing $0.

Comment: Not only is $0 mutable, [so is `__FILE__`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsyn.html#Plain-Old-Comments-%28Not%21%29).