# Accessing subs from a require'd perl script

Tags: perl, namespaces

I'm going to import some perl code with the `require` statement. The code I'd like to import is in `mylibA.pl`:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
package FOO::BAR;

sub routine {
    print "A message!\n";
}
```

and `mylibB.pl`:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
package FOO::BAZ;

sub routine {
    print "Another message!\n";
}
```

Then I'm going to use it like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
foreach my $lib (qw/ mylibA.pl mylibB.pl /){
     require $lib;
     print "Make a call to ${lib}'s &routine!\n";
}
```

Is there a way for my script to figure out the namespace that was pulled in with the `require` statement?

Comment: This seems like a *horrid* design; you will be much better off with a proper plugin system. Still, an interesting question.

Comment: Is there somewhere that describes how proper plugins can be handled in perl?

Comment: BTW, my design requires that the plugin's are standalone executable.. this is the only way I've been able to come up with. What specifically is horrid about this design?

Comment: When you say "I'm going to use it like this" ... what do you mean?  You don't show us an actual invocation of either definition of `routine()`; instead we only see the 'require' lines.  What, really, are you trying to do and what, really, have you tried?

Comment: @pilcrow: This print statement in the loop is describing in English what I'd like to do in Perl. I want to be able to call a particular `&routine` by knowing the path to the `.pl` file in which it lives.

Comment: You know the `.pl` filenames, but you do _not_ know the package names in which they define `routine`.  E.g., you know that `yourlibA.pl` has a sub, but you don't know that it's in `Foo::Bar`, is that right?

Comment: Yep, that's exactly my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two problems here:

1. How do I change the behaviour of a script when executed as a standalone and when used as a module?
2. How do I discover the package name of a piece of code I just compiled?

The general answer to question 2 is: You don't, as any compilation unit may contain an arbitrary number of packages.

Anyway, here are three possible solutions:

1. Name your modules so that you already know the name when you load it.
2. Have each module register itself at a central rendezvous point.
3. Like #1, but adds autodiscovery of your plugins.

The simplest solution is to put all of the API in an ordinary module, and put the standalone logic in a seperate script:

```
/the/location/
  Module/
    A.pm
    B.pm
  a-standalone.pl
  b-standalone.pl
```

Where each standalone basically looks like

```
use Module::A;
Module::A->run();
```

If another script wants to reuse that code, it does

```
use lib "/the/location";
use Module::A;
...
```

If the loading happens on runtime, then `Module::Runtime` helps here:

```
use Module::Runtime 'use_module';
use lib "/the/location";
my $mod_a = use_module('Module::A');
$mod_a->run();
```

It isn't strictly necessary to place the contents of `a-standalone.pl` and `Module/A.pm` into separate files, although that is clearer. If you want to conditionally run code in a module only if it is used as a script, you can utilize [the `unless(caller)` trick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/707022/is-there-a-perl-equivalent-to-pythons-if-name-main).

---

Of course all of this is tricksing: Here we determine the file name from the module name, not the other way round – which as I already mentioned we cannot do.

What we can do is have each module register itself at a certain predefined location, e.g. by

```
Rendezvous::Point->register(__FILE__ => __PACKAGE__);
```

Of course the standalone version has to shield against the possibility that there is no `Rendezvous::Point`, therefore:

```
if (my $register = Rendezvous::Point->can("register")) {
  $register->(__FILE__ => __PACKAGE__);
}
```

Eh, this is silly and violates DRY. So let's create a `Rendezvous::Point` module that takes care of this:

In `/the/location/Rendezvous/Point.pm`:

```
package Rendezvous::Point;
use strict; use warnings;

my %modules_by_filename;

sub get {
  my ($class, $name) = @_;
  $modules_by_filename{$name};
}

sub register {
  my ($file, $package) = @_;
  $modules_by_filename{$file} = $package;
}

sub import {
  my ($class) = @_;
  $class->register(caller());
}
```

Now, `use Rendezvous::Point;` registers the calling package, and the module name can be retrived by the absolute path.

The script that wants to use the various modules now does:

```
use "/the/location";
use Rendezvous::Point ();  # avoid registering ourself

my $prefix = "/the/location";
for my $filename (map "$prefix/$_", qw(Module/A.pm Module/B.pm)) {
  require $filename;
  my $module  = Rendezvous::Point->get($filename)
             // die "$filename didn't register itself at the Rendezvous::Point";
  $module->run();
}
```

---

Then there are fully featured plugin systems like [`Module::Pluggable`](https://metacpan.org/module/Module::Pluggable). This system works by looking at all paths were Perl modules may reside, and loads them if they have a certain prefix. A solution with that would look like:

```
/the/location/
  MyClass.pm
  MyClass/
    Plugin/
      A.pm
      B.pm
  a-standalone.pl
  b-standalone.pl
```

Everything is just like with the first solution: Standalone scripts look like

```
use lib "/the/location/";
use MyClass::Plugin::A;
MyClass::Plugin::A->run;
```

But `MyClass.pm` looks like:

```
package MyClass;
use Module::Pluggable require => 1;  # we can now query plugins like MyClass->plugins

sub run {
  # Woo, magic! Works with inner packages as well!
  for my $plugin (MyClass->plugins) {
    $plugin->run();
  }
}
```

Of course, this still requires a specific naming scheme, but it auto-discovers possible plugins.

Answer (score 5):

Wow. I have to say this is the one of the most interesting Perl questions I've seen in a while. On the surface this seems like a very simple request - get an included module's namespace, but there really is no way to do this. You can get it while in the package, but not from outside the package. I tried using EXPORT to send the local package name back to the caller script but that ended up going nowhere given the difference in how "use" and "require" work. A more module type of approach probably would have worked with a "use" statement, but the requirement that the required script be able to run by themselves prevented that approach. The only thing left to do was to directly pollute the caller's namespace and hope for the best (assume that the caller had no package namespace) - something that modules are designed to prevent.

BTW - I can't believe this actually works - in strict mode, no less.

caller.pl

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;

#package SomePackageName; #if you enable this then this will fail to work

our $ExportedPackageName;

print "Current package=".__PACKAGE__."\n";

foreach my $lib (qw/ mylibA.pl mylibB.pl /){
    require $lib;
    print "Make a call to ${lib}'s &routine!\n";
    print "Package name exported=".$ExportedPackageName."\n";
    $ExportedPackageName->routine;
} #end foreach

print "Normal Exit";
exit;

__END__
```

mylibA.pl

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
package FOO::BAR;
use strict;

#better hope the caller does not have a package namespace
$main::ExportedPackageName=__PACKAGE__;

sub routine {
    print "A message from ".__PACKAGE__."!\n";
}

1;
```

mylibB.pl

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
package FOO::BAZ;
use strict;

#better hope the caller does not have a package namespace
$main::ExportedPackageName=__PACKAGE__;

sub routine {
    print "Another message, this time from ".__PACKAGE__."!\n";
}

1;
```

Result:

```
c:\Perl>
c:\Perl>perl caller.pl
Current package=main
Make a call to mylibA.pl's &routine!
Package name exported=FOO::BAR
A message from FOO::BAR!
Make a call to mylibB.pl's &routine!
Package name exported=FOO::BAZ
Another message, this time from FOO::BAZ!
Normal Exit
```

Comment: This is Perl giving you enough rope to hang yourself.

Comment: I couldn't agree more, and I'm still amazed you can do this.

Answer (score 2):

Regarding the mostly academical problem of finding the package(s) in a perl source file:

You can try the CPAN module [Module::Extract::Namespaces](https://metacpan.org/module/Module%3a%3aExtract%3a%3aNamespaces) to get all packages within a perl file. It is using PPI and is thus not 100% perfect, but most of the time good enough:

```
perl -MModule::Extract::Namespaces -e 'warn join ",", Module::Extract::Namespaces->from_file(shift)' /path/to/foo.pm
```

But PPI can be slow for large files.

You can try to compare the active packages before and after the require. This is also not perfect, because if your perl library file loads additional modules then you cannot tell which is the package of the prinicipal file and what's loaded later. To get the list of packages you can use for example [Devel::Symdump](https://metacpan.org/module/Devel%3a%3aSymdump). Here's a sample script:

```
use Devel::Symdump;

my %before = map { ($_,1) } Devel::Symdump->rnew->packages;
require "/path/to/foo.pm";
my %after  = map { ($_,1) } Devel::Symdump->rnew->packages;

delete $after{$_} for keys %before;
print join(",", keys %after), "\n";
```

You can also just parse the perl file for "package" declarations. Actually, that's what the PAUSE upload daemon is doing, so it's probably "good enough" for most cases. Look at the subroutine `packages_per_pmfile` in
https://github.com/andk/pause/blob/master/lib/PAUSE/pmfile.pm

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned before it is not possible to look up the namespace of a 'required' package without extra I/O, guessing or assuming.

Like Rick said before, one have to intrude the namespace of the caller or better 'main'. I prefer to inject specific hooks within a BEGIN block of the 'required' package.

```
#VENDOR/App/SocketServer/Protocol/NTP.pm
package VENDOR::App::SocketServer::Protocol::NTP;

BEGIN {
  no warnings;
  *main::HANDLE_REQUEST = \&HANDLE_REQUEST;
}

sub HANDLE_REQUEST {
}

#VENDOR/App/SocketServer.pm
my $userPackage= $ARGV[0];
require $userPackage;
main::HANDLE_REQUEST();
```

Instead of *main:: you can get more specific with *main::HOOKS::HANDLE_REQUESTS i.e. This enables you to resolve all injected hooks easily within the caller by iterating over the HOOK's namespace portion.

```
foreach my $hooks( keys %main::HOOKS ) {

}
```