# TCL equivalent to Python's `if __name__ == "__main__"`

Tags: tcl

In one executable TCL script I'm defining a variable that I'd like to import in another executable TCL script. In Python one can make a combined library and executable by using the following idiom at the bottom of one's script:

```
# Library

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # Executable that depends on library
    pass
```

Is there something equivalent for TCL? [There is for Perl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/707022/is-there-a-perl-equivalent-to-pythons-if-name-main).

**Edit:** The answer given by Donal Fellows is entirely sufficient, but for completion the comments below are gathered into one final answer here:

```
if {[info exists ::argv0] && $::argv0 eq [file normalize [info script]]} {
    # Do the things for if the script is run as a program...
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The equivalent for Tcl is to compare the `::argv0` global variable to the result of the `info script` command.

```
if {$::argv0 eq [info script]} {
    # Do the things for if the script is run as a program...
}
```

The `::argv0` global (technically a feature of the standard `tclsh` and `wish` shells, or anything else that calls `Tcl_Main` or `Tk_Main` at the C level) has the name of the main script, or is the empty string if there is no main script. The `info script` command returns the name of the file currently being evaluated, whether that's by `source` or because of the main shell is running it as a script. They'll be the same thing when the current script is the main script.

---

As mrcalvin notes in the comments below, if your library script is sometimes used in contexts where `argv0` is not set (custom shells, child interpreters, embedded interpreters, some application servers, etc.) then you should add a bit more of a check first:

```
if {[info exists ::argv0] && $::argv0 eq [info script]} {
    # Do the things for if the script is run as a program...
}
```

Comment: You might want to generalize to obtain `if {[info exists ::argv0] && $::argv0 eq [info script]}`, just to make your script does not throw up in environments that don't run `Tcl_Main` (e.g., NaviServer, some embedded Tcl).

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I stumbled across http://wiki.tcl.tk/40097 which tries to `[file normalize [info script]/...]` in various complicated ways; is this essential?

Comment: It is good practise, yes, and helps avoid confusion in corner cases, when you use relative paths etc. The `file dirname` and `file normalize` mambo jumbo seems complicated only at first glance.

Answer (score 1):

I recently wanted this functionality to set up some unit tests for my HDL build scripts suite. This is what i ended up with for Vivado:

```
proc is_main_script {} {                                               ;# +1 frame
    set frame [info frame [expr [info frame] -3]]
    if {![dict exists $frame file]} {
        set command [file normalize [lindex [dict get $frame cmd] 1]]
        set script  [file normalize [info script]] 
        if {$script eq $command} {
            return 1
        } else {
            return 0
        }
    } else {
        return 0
    }
}

if {is_main_script} {                                                  ;# +1 frame 
    puts "do your thing"
}
```

As I consider this for test/demo i consider the main use case to be something in the line with `if {is_main_script} {puts "do something"}` "un nested" at the end of the file.

If a need to make it more general a dynamic handle for the `frame` reference `-3` could probably be developed. All though this has covered all my use cases so far.

`frame` `-3` is used as `proc` and `if` creates extra frames and to evaluate this we want to check the call before.

`dict exists` is used to check if `file` exists within the frame. This would indicate the call was from a higher hierarchical level script and would there for not be the "main_script"

The solution `if {[info exists ::argv0] && $::argv0 eq [info script]}` works great if run as `vivado -source TCLSCRIPT.tcl` but the solution above covers `source TCLSCRIPT.tcl` in gui or tcl mode (this is something i often se my self doing when debugging a automation tcl).

I guess this is a niche case. But since I couldn't find any other solution for this problem I wanted to leave this here.